# ReactJS - How to route views with ES5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Most of the `ReactJs` guides that i've found are based in `ES5`. So i've started to use `ReactJS` in this way. 
Now that i know how to create all my `components` it's time to create a little `single-page-application`. My trouble is to understand how to `route` my `views` without reload the page. I've find `react-router` (https://github.com/rackt/react-router) and this seems what i need for my aim, but all the examples are written in `ES6` and currently it's not yet clear to me.
Surely i'll refactor my app in ES6, but i'd prefer to follow the way i've started.

Is there someone who could help me to "translate" react-router to ES5 and let me get this clearer please?

Comment: sure, what kind of problems are you having? also [Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=) might be useful for you

Comment: First of all thank you very much. I just need a clear example in ES5 of this tool, i need to route my views like a simple SPA

Comment: Basically you can follow the docs (check the Introduction part) as is. The only things you want to do differently are the `imports`. Check the answer below. For ES6 I highly recommend reading this: http://exploringjs.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example for you from *react-route* tutorial

```
render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

Components App, About, Inbox, Message were created with ES6 syntax but it doesn't matter it also translates your ES6 syntax to the ES5 using babel, so you can easily pass there your ES5 components.

Also, this two lines of code:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
```

means:

```
var render = require('react-dom').render;
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: you did! thanks! can i ask you how to "clean" my url? now i get `http://localhost:8080/#/about?_k=zrvxqc`. I'd prefer a classic url like `http://localhost:8080/about`

Comment: Actually you can't do it, that how react-router works. All the time you will get http://localhost:8080/# as a home url but on your server side you can target it as '/' url and you will get expected result. Also i've found some [Link](http://geek.bluemangointeractive.com/react-router-an-introduction/) for you. I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks again my friend! i'll give a lecture!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer forgot to mention about the BrowserHistory, which is an essential part of the ReactRouter. You can level up [here](https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/).

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var SchoolsList = require("./components/SchoolsList.jsx");

var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link

var browserHistory = Router.browserHistory;



var _question = schoolsStore.getQuestion();

function render(){
    //console.log(_question);
    ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={SchoolsList} question={_question.question} activeIndex={_question.activeIndex} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("container"));
}

render();
```